# SQL Haversine Formula

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @Lat1 AS DECIMAL(9,5)
DECLARE @Lon1 AS DECIMAL(9,5)
DECLARE @Radius AS DECIMAL(9,5)

SET @Lat1 = '32.74'   
SET @Lon1 = '-117.20'
SET @Radius = 3960

declare @CC decimal(9,5),@CS decimal(9,5),@rlat decimal(9,5),@slat decimal(9,5)

Select 
    @CC = cos(RADIANS(@Lat1))*cos(RADIANS(@Lon1))
    , @CS = cos(RADIANS(@Lat1))*sin(RADIANS(@Lon1))
    , @slat = Sin(radians(@lat1))

SELECT 
    call_id, dtservertime, sdisconnectreason,
    icompleted, Geolat, Geolong, sZipCode
FROM 
    (SELECT
        call_id, dtServerTime, sDisconnectReason,
        iCompleted, Geolat, Geolong, sZipCode
        ,convert(decimal(9,5),radians(geoLat)) as Rlat
        ,convert(decimal(9,5),radians(geoLong)) as Rlong
    FROM
        dbo.vMarketing) as x
WHERE 
    x.dtservertime >= '1/1/2016' and 
    (acos(
        @cc*(cos(rlat)*cos(RLONG) )
   +   @cs*(cos(RLAT)*sin(RLONG) )
   +   @SLat*sin(RLAT)
  ) * @Radius
) < 8
```

I keep on getting an error on this query saying that An invalid floating point operation occurred.

What is wrong???

Comment: The value  being passed to `acos` function is out-of-range as explained in the answer, which is causing this floating point error.

Comment: The real question is: why implement the Haversine formula in T-SQL at all? Since SQL 2008, we've had the geography data type which will allows you to compute the distance between two points natively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a valid value to the `acos` function i.e. the value passed must be between -1 and +1. So the following queries would cause the `floating point error` in SQL Server.

**Queries that will cause floating point error**

```
select acos(-1.1);
select acos(2.5);
```

**Queries that will NOT cause floating point error**

```
select acos(-1.0);
select acos(0.7);
```

From Math we know that cosine of an angle will always lie between -1 and +1.

In your situation the following expression  which you are passing to `acos` function evaluates to something outside the range of -1 to +1.

```
@cc * ( COS(rlat) * COS(RLONG) ) + @cs * ( COS(RLAT) * SIN(RLONG) ) + @SLat * SIN(RLAT)
```

You can see in screen shot below how this invalid function call behaves in SQL Server Management Studio.

**Screen Shot of out-of-range acos call in SSMS**

[image: Floating Point Error in acos function]